# What are the "books of experiments" the Ramban refers to when noting a infant which nurses from a pig will become a leper?

Tags: medicine, ramban

The [Ramban in Leviticus 11:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Leviticus.11.13.1?lang=bi) writes:

(*Source from [Sefaria.org](https://www.sefaria.org/)*)

(*Partial Quote*)

> וראיתי בקצת ספרי הנסיונות שחלב החזיר אם ינק היונק ממנו יהיה אותו הנער מצורע
>
> *I saw in some of the "books of experiments" regarding the milk of a pig, that if a infant which nurses from it, the infant will become a leper*

What are the "books of experiments" the Ramban is referring too? Is there any known manuscript which cites this finding ?

Comment: likely just quackery medicine from his time... Sorry!

Comment: @רבותמחשבות noted, but *which* book of quackery

Comment: I'm sure that there were very many.  Even the Ramban himself notes that it's only in some of them

Comment: I did look around for such a theory in secular literature, but haven't found it yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a common early belief, and is associated with Egyptians.  It is highly likely that there were many books that the Ramban had access to that supported such a theory, although we have no way of knowing which one(s), since the Ramban doesn't refer to these books anywhere else in his writings.

See [this excellent Devar Torah/article](http://alex-klein.co.il/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA-%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%90%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%97%D7%96%D7%99%D7%A8-%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%94-%D7%93%D7%AA/) (on this week's Parsha) by [Professor Alexander Klein](http://alex-klein.co.il) where he discusses the link between Tzaraas and pigs in Jewish sources, but he does also mention a couple of non-Jewish sources.

One example of where this can be found is in [Plutarch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutarch)'s Isis and Osris ([here](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Plutarch/Moralia/Isis_and_Osiris*/A.html#note35), p21, fn 35 provides more sources):

> In like manner they hold the pig to be an unclean animal, because it is reputed to be most inclined to mate in the waning of the moon, **and because the bodies of those who drink its milk break out with leprosy and scabrous itching**.

Additional note: Chavel notes that in Rabbeinu Bachya/Bechayay, the quote of Ramban reads Sifrei Harefuos, or medical books:

> וראיתי בקצת **ספרי הרפואות** שחלב החזיר אם ינק היונק ממנו יהיה אותו נער מצורע, וזה לאות שיש בכלן סגולות רעות מאד, עד כאן.

These are quoted by Ramban on a number of occasions (see [here](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Search?mode=basic&t=%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%20%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA) for search results), but I don't know what particular books Ramban consulted for medical advice...  Chavel makes no comments in those places, either.

Comment: James Frazer in the Golden Bough also makes note of it. See Chapter 49:4

Comment: @TrustMeI'mARabbi Feel free to edit it in; it's at this link: http://www.bartleby.com/196/118.html